# Break on thread creation in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, multithreading, debugging

Can I set the Visual Studio debugger to break on thread creation?

(Note this is not the same as breaking on context switch as asked for in this other question: [Can I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio (c++) to break on a thread context switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048064/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-c-to-break-on-a-thread-context-switch))

Comment: @Derek Tomes: I did not.  I'm not working with Windows or Visual Studio these days, so I am no longer looking for a solution myself.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a way to do it. While googling I saw the opposite question:
[Is it possible to break on thread exit with specific error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163785/is-it-possible-to-break-on-thread-exit-with-specific-error-code)

I put a breakpoint at the function `RtlExitUserThread`, after that I realized that all threads was creating with the function `RtlUserThreadStart`, so put another breakpoint to that function and that's all :)

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how **exactly** you "put a breakpoint at the function RtlUserThreadStart"? I seem to be unable to put any breakpoints on windows internal dll functions even with techniques explained in other posts.

Comment: In visual studio, in the Breakpoints window (Debug / Windows / Breakpoints or Alt+F9) you can set breakpoints to functions symbols. Click on "New" / "Functions Breakpoint..." or Ctrl+B in the Breakpoints window and enter the function name in the dialog box, in this case RtlUserThreadStart. For me it's working even without loading microsoft ntdll.pdb symbols.

Comment: Okay that is odd. I have exports and symbols enabled and never did a breakpoint on `RtlUserThreadStart` hit... I was however able to find out the stdcall signature of it which the debugger successfully breaks on. Also Kudos to Visual Studio for not giving any error message when the creation of a new breakpoint fails for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by @George, there are two functions you can break on. If you want to find out *what creates the new thread* you should break on thread creating WINAPI function calls such as `CreateThread` or `_beginthread(ex)`. If you want to break into the start of the newly created thread (on the call stack of that thread itself) you should break into `RtlUserThreadStart`.

However, there are two prerequisites to be able to break into either of these:

**1. Symbol downloading from Microsoft Servers needs to be enabled**

For the breakpoints to work the debugger needs to know some basic symbol information of the native dlls. Make sure symbol loading from MS servers is enabled (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols)

**2. You need the actual stdcall signatures of the target functions**

For some reason even with enabled export loading VS was unable to find the functions I needed to break on for me. So I went checking what the actual signatures are. This can be done by using the [dumpbin cmd line tool of VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c1h23y6c.aspx), or by running a short test on the code:

```
void* ptr = CreateThread;
```

Running this code in the debugger reveals the address and signature of the `CreateThread` for example which is `_CreateThreadStub@24` for me (Win7 32-bit application). For `RtlUserThreadStart` it was `___RtlUserThreadStart@8` for me.

**3. Setting the breakpoint**

Now it's as easy as choosing Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Break at Function. For the function name you put either `_CreateThreadStub@24` or `___RtlUserThreadStart@8` and leave the rest be.

This then triggers when a new thread is being created.

**Observation**

`_CreateThreadStub@24` seems to cover the CreateThread, _beginthread and _beginthreadex functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the thread is being created by the managed Thread class, then a simple solution would be to put a breakpoint on its entry (by going to the Breakpoints window, clicking New->Break at function and marking Thread.Start).

Otherwise, as Hans said, you would have to use a more complex solution like mdbg, or using a open-source implementation of CLR profiler (like [SAE](http://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/)) and putting an "asm int 3" instruction in the ICorProfilerCallback::ThreadCreated method.

Also, if you have VS2010 Ultimate, you could just look up the Thread Created event in Intellitrace events, and possibly get the information you need from there (though this will not break when the thread is created, but rather give you some info about the stack trace/variable values at the time it was created, in retrospect).

Comment: A related hint is that going into Breakpoint toolwindow (Ctrl+Alt+B), hitting Add Breakpoint and typing Foo.Foo (where Foo is a name of class, like Thread or BackgroundWorker), it would put breakpoints on all the constructors of Foo.

Comment: Just added a breakpoint for `Thread.Start` as soon as my application started, VS caught it. Then, I had no way of resuming and everytime I clicked on VS2010, it would tell me it is waiting on a process. Point being, don't add the breakpoint until your application starts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the debugger gets a notification for it.  No, the UI doesn't allow you to tell it to break on that notification.  If this is for managed code then you could use the MDbg sample and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 potential things you could mean when you say you want to break on thread creation:

1. Break inside the creating thread BEFORE the new thread has been created
2. Break inside the NEW thread before the user-provided function is called.

For the first option, you'll want to break in CreateThread, _beginthread, or _beginthreadex.

For the second option, you'll want to break in RtlUserThreadStart or BaseThreadInitThunk to catch the new thread early in its execution before user code gets called.

Unfortunately, Visual studio won't break in those functions if you create a breakpoint with the function names I've listed above, at least not by default. The problem is that for native debugging, it doesn't load DLL exports by default, and without that, the debugger has no idea where to find the names I've provided above.

Before you start debugging, in Visual Studio go to tools, options, debugging, then expand the debugging options tree in the left pane. Then click on "native" and check "Load DLL Exports". Then you can start debugging your executable again.

After that, you should be able to create a breakpoint on any of the functions I mentioned by typing in the name. You may or may not need to specify the DLL the function is in by creating the breakpoint with the name as follows:

{,,kernel32.dll}CreateThread

or

{,,ntdll.dll}RtlUserThreadStart

I got this information by starting here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/reiley/2011/07/26/debugging-tips-for-multi-threaded-application/

and doing some experimenting on my own. I know this is a response to an old question but I hope this saves other people some of the pain I've had when trying to debug crashes that happen immediately upon thread startup.

Comment: The first helpful answer on this topic... I was scrolling too long for this. The only issue I still have with your explanation is that the breakpoints set via the {,,dll}FuncName convention still don't seem to trigger. I had to do some hacky pointer copying to get to the stdcall signatures of these functions which then seemed to trigger. Not sure if that's only an issue on my end however. I'll write another answer just in case someone still reads up on that.

Comment: This was very heplful, thanks. However, are you sure that you have to restart the VisualStudio and load exports? I just have a process halted mid-work, and writing CreateThread or _beginthreadex in the `Watch` panel, I can see their addresses just fine. Actually, addresses of import thunks leading to them. On the other hand, if I paste `{,,kernel32.dll}CreateThread` in Watch, I get `kernel32.dll!0x00007ffe8659b540 (load symbols for additional information)`. I was able to use this `kernel32.dll!0x00007ffe8659b540` in 'break at function' and it caught it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint at the first call to `CreateThread` (maybe you insert a fake call for this purpose).
When hit, change from Source Code View to Disassemly View and step into the call. Go through the ImportLib-Code and set a breakpoint. Not perfect, but it works.