# Is it possible to trap thread start and end events?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I've inherited a reasonably large visual studio WinForms project in C# and VB.Net

While I'm working with it, I get messages in the Debug window like this:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1194) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x664) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x14b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

In an effort to better understand the software, I'm curious to investigate what these threads are. Are there any tools I can use or or debugging options I can turn on that will allow me to break when new threads are created / terminated?

Note: I've stuck breakpoints on all the  "... = new Thread" and "... .RunWorkerAsync()" code I can find and it's none of them.

Comment: Any time a `Task.Run` (or it is used internally by a method that returns a `Task`) is used it also could potentially create a Thread if there are no live threads in the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exact answer to your question, but here is some related information that have been posted to another question: [Break on thread creation in Visual Studio debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820854/break-on-thread-creation-in-visual-studio-debugger)

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty much like what I'm asking but it went unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

In the Thread class there is a name property that you can set. When you change it, the "No Name" text in the output will be replaced with what you set there. This will make it easier for you to see what is going on.

```
Thread MyThread = new Thread(...);
MyThread.Name = "MyName"; //Can only be set once.
MyThread.Start(....);
```

Comment: Thanks Harry! Unfortunately I have no idea what is starting the threads which is the problem I was trying to solve. I hoped that if I could trap thread start and stop events I could also find out what was creating them.